# Command Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, server

I tried this command `rails server`, then I get this error

```
/usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `gem install rails`

Comment: I tried but i get the same error, I must be install others dependencies?

Comment: uninstall and install rails gem.

Comment: Are you running the command from the folder where your project is located?

Comment: maybe try install with rvm

Comment: i try in genieacs-gui

Comment: @HRIZI did u create new rails app `rails new my_app` ?

Comment: no, I just run the command `rails server` in the folder genieacs-gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands:

1. `gem update --system`
2. `bundle install`
3. `rails server`

Or as a one-liner:

```
gem update --system; bundle install; rails server
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to run following command:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

and

```
sudo bundle install
```

and start your terminal again after closing once, then execute..

**`rails server`**

Comment: Thanks! It helped me also! I ve got the following error:
/usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to install rbenv via homebrew in case you install ti with rvm. I also had some trouble with rvm but this worked for me.

Also you can start your rails server only if you are in your project folder.

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.3.1
rbenv global 2.3.1
ruby -v
```

And then install rails

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.6
rbenv rehash
rails -v
# Rails 4.2.6
```

Comment: I tried then I type the command `sudo rails server` in the folder genieacs-gui, then i get this error `/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'tzinfo' (~> 1.1) among 85 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)`